# php : cannot update field in database (PDO) by multiple choice of checkbox

Tags: mysql, checkbox, pdo

I got the problem when tried to update the field in the database using the checkbox,
if `checkbox` checked, after that I press button to update.

the output program doesn't work

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="id1<?php echo $data['id'];?>" value="id1<?php echo $data['id'];?>" ></td>;
```

**update code:**

```
<?php
foreach($result as $data) { // display all data in table before we updated
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id1<?php echo $data['id'];?>" value="id1<?php echo $data['id'];?>" ></td>;

    $update = "UPDATE identitas SET status='1'  WHERE nama=".$data["id"];
    // if button update clicke
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    // if checkbox is checked
        if(isset($_POST['id1'])) {
            if($conn->exec($update)===TRUE){
                echo "success update";
            }else{
                echo "failed Update" . $conn->errorInfo();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
//other codes
```

when the checkbox is checked, I will update the field `status` in the database from 0 to be 1

my code above doesn't work, I use PDO

Answer (score 0):

The two lines of code I quote here below are not compatible with each other.

For example if $data['id'] contains the value 3, then the name of the checkbox would be 'id13', whereas you check for a POST variable named 'id1'.

```
if(isset($_POST['id1'])) {

name="id1<?php echo $data['id'];?>"
```

Comment: in order word i should check `if(isset($_POST[id1['id]]))`? sorry for fools example, i have tried a lot of way to make this program run well, it makes me confused enough

Comment: I think you should separate the two values. id for the name, and data['id'] for the value. Then you would only have to check the POST variable $_POST['id']

Comment: are you meant like this : `<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="id1<?php echo $data['id'];?>" >` then i check `if(isset($_POST['id]))`?

Answer (score -1):

**change name to update and run your code**

`<td><input type="checkbox" name="Update" value="id1<?php echo $data['id'];?>" ></td>`

or you can change like this,

```
if(isset($_POST['id1'])) {

name="id1<?php echo $data['id'];?>
```

Comment: could you detail me, which one name for update (button update) and which one name for checkbox?. i mean, the name of update of your answer i used for name of button update